# Unable to detect elements inside iframe in Internet explorer selenium driver

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-iedriver

This failed with the error : Unable to find element with xpath == //body
It fails to find elements under frame in internet explorer.
This code works fine in Chrome.
Please help me to figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
var descFrame= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[starts- 
with(@id,'description')]"));
string name = descFrame.GetAttribute("name");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(name);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys("Hello World");
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Selenium sometimes issue with switching to iframe by ID on Internet Explorer,if possible try switching to frame by index
      driver.switchTo().frame(1);